# Python - iterate through a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate email reporting using python. My problem is that i cant pull the `subject` from the data that my email client outputs.

Abbreviated dataset:

```
[(messageObject){
   id = "0bd503eb00000000000000000000000d0f67"
   name = "11.26.17 AM [TXT-CAT]{Shoppers:2}"
   status = "active"
   messageFolderId = "0bd503ef0000000000000000000000007296"
   content[] = 
      (messageContentObject){
         type = "html"
         subject = "Early Cyber Monday – 60% Off Sitewide "
         }
         }
         ]
```

I can pull the other fields like this:

```
messageId = []
messageName = []
subject = []

for info in messages:
    messageId.append(str(info['id']))
    messageName.append(str(info['name']))
    subject.append(str(info[content['subject']]))

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': messageId,
    'name': messageName,
    'subject': subject
}) 
data.head()
```

I've been trying to iterate though `content[]` using a for loop, but i can't get it to work. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: What happens when you iterate through `content` using a `for` loop? Exception or bad data?

Comment: What format is the output of your email client? Presumably you receive it as JSON?

Comment: @FamousJameous the main problem is that i can't get the syntax correct (i'm learing as i go)

Comment: @roganjosh Not sure, i pulled it from the Bronto API and it doesn't work like a JSON file - i tried making it work with json.load and it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: That format is called SOAP. My guess for the syntax would be  `info['content']['subject']` or maybe `info['content'][0]['subject']`.

Comment: `info['content'][0]['subject']` worked. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@FamousJameous gave the correct answer:

That format is called SOAP. My guess for the syntax would be `info['content']['subject']` or maybe `info['content'][0]['subject']`

`info['content'][0]['subject']` worked with my data.